# Creating a HeatMap in R with 2 Variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, heatmap

I'm trying to create a HeatMap in R in order to visualize the following [data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15affMdVo6MPQ0ssCWmwSo2un8MxNRjXQUUa9zSi-m28/pubhtml).

```
State    Discount
LA      0.118749612
MO      0.127916129
IA      0.129584375
NE      0.138754902
GA      0.146281061
```

I don't have a lot of experience beyond simply using the built in `heatmap()` function. However because the state variable is a factor this doesn't work. My next thought was to try and use `ggplot2`

```
ggplot(data = dat, aes(State))+ geom_tile( fill = dat$Discount)
```

However I keep getting this error which I don't fully understand.

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'y' not found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(diff(sort(x))) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

I'm not necessarily sure that a heatmap is the best way to visualize my data it was just my first thought. I'm also looking into using the `mapdata` package to plot a US map showing these differences in discount level by color but haven't come up with a good way of doing so yet. Any help I can get would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You don't need `dat$` in front of `Discount`

Comment: If I don't I get: `Error in layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomTile,  : 
  object 'Discount' not found`

Comment: And heatmaps need an y-variable, and fill needs to be mapped inside aes. Furthermore, not sure you why you want a heatmap. They are generally used to show the value of something for combinations of other things. Might you be needing a barplot?

Comment: In addition: `fill` needs to be inside `aes()`, and you need both x and y, not sure what you want to plot here.

Comment: I think a barplot is more appropriate in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wound up visualizing my data as follows:

First I added a column to my original data so that I could merge it with state data available in R. So my data file (called `GregUSHeatMap`) would now look something like this:

```
State          Code   Discount
vermont         VT    0.02
maine           ME    0.025
massachusetts   MA    0.042073333
south dakota    SD    0.074503704
```

Then I ran the following:

```
require(mapdata)
states <- map_data("state")
merge <- merge(states, GregUSheatmap, by = "region")
merge <- arrange(merge, order)
heatmap1 <- qplot(long, lat, data = merge, group = group, fill = Discount, geom = "polygon")
```

Producing the following:
[image]